# how to hide search result box, I want them to be shown up when keyup function is hit and gets activated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, django

Hello I have search engine that's run with calling ajax function. when user types "T" then the result "TEST" pops up. I'm using keyup function that when I don't type anything it stays calm. Problem is I made a box where the result to be shown, and right now the box is shown up when the keyup function is being called. I want to hide this box, and want this to show up when user types something in a search box. Here's my code.

```
 <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          {% csrf_token %}
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" name="search" onkeyup="handle_keyup()" placeholder="search"/></div>
      </form>

<div class="search-box">
  <ul id="search-results">

</ul>
</div>
```

the ajax,

```
function handle_keyup() {

       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "/search/",
           data: { 
               'search_text' : $('#search').val(),
               'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
           },
           success: searchSuccess,
           dataType: 'html'
       });

   }
```

;

the css for the box

```
.search-box{
  border: 5px solid black;
  width:100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-left: 170px;
}



function searchSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
{
   $('#search-results').html(data);
}
```

this is ajax search.html(probably not relevant but I'll post anyway)

```
{% if categories.count > 0 %}

{% for category in categories %}
   <li><a href="/category/{{category.name}}">{{ category.name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}

{% else %}

<li>None to show!</li>

{% endif %}
```

So to make this post clear, what I'm trying to do is what Stack Overflow does. When you type something in a title section, similar questions pop up right?but untill then nothing shows up. I'm trying to make it like that....thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>

<script> 
        $(function() {
           $("#search").on("keypress",function(event){("#search-results").show();});
         }
</script>

<body>
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" class="form-control" visibility="hidden" id="search" name="search" onkeyup="handle_keyup()" placeholder="search"/></div>
   </form>

<div class="search-box">
  <ul id="search-results">

  </ul>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: I'm sorry I'm having a hard time understanding your answer, so replace visibility wit onkeyup??and put juqery where??do you mind showing me through the code please??

Comment: yeah like i expected, this doesn't work. I'm using keyup function it doesn't makesense to delete onkeyup...

Comment: Clearer? This should work, the keypress event will show the div, then the keyup will run the ajax. You can use the same syntax for the keyup actually $("#search").on("keyup",function(even){do something;});